# Cant make use of classes in files that are called by cron job

Tags: php, ajax, cron

I have some files that are called by cron jobs or ajax calls.
In all of these files I can't make any use of classes.

**Example:**

```
    <?php
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/includes.php");

$result = "query result"
foreach ($result as $row) {
    //Send Invoice
            $invoice= new Invoice;
            $rand = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),4);
            $rand .= '-'.substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),4);
            $rand .= '-'.substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),4);
            $invoiceName = strtoupper($rand);
}
```

Includes.php includes all my classes.

**Includes.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'functions/connection.php'; 
include_once 'functions/functions.php';
require_once 'functions/MPDF/mpdf.php';

$classes = scandir('classes');
$length = count($classes);

for($i = 2; $i < $length; $i++) {
    include_once 'classes/'.$classes[$i];
}
```

Normally that will give me an instance of Invoice. But when the php file is called with cronjobs or ajax, it doesn't create an instance of Invoice.
I tried to include the class files, but this didnt work either.

Is this a known thing?

*************UPDATE***************
Made a rookie mistake. It worked when I used `dirname(__FILE__)`, but in my code below I forgot that I needed to go 1 directory up. `dirname(__FILE__)."../includes.php"` did the trick.

Comment: What *does* it do? Do it create something else? Does it output an error message? Do you have error reporting turned up high?

Comment: Thats the thing. I don't receive any errors. My error_log file logs nothing. I tried to mail error to my email, tried logging errors to the database. But I just don't get any... Thats why this is so frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the path of your include call?

I once had a script I called regularly from the browser and it had relative include paths. However, when called via Cron it didn't work. When I changed these to physical it did :)

Comment: Thank you!! It didn't work with relative paths. `dirname(__FILE__)` did the trick :)